# Possible bug in CFStringCreateByCombiningStrings

Tags: cocoa, macos

I've got a problem with CFStringCreateByCombiningString that i can't solve.  Seems to evade explanation:

```
CFMutableArrayRef filename_arr = CFArrayCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

// insert prefix
int part_prefix = part + 1;
CFStringRef part_str = CFNumberFormatterCreateStringWithValue(kCFAllocatorDefault, format_ref, kCFNumberIntType, &part_prefix);
CFArraySetValueAtIndex(filename_arr, 0, part_str);

// insert prefix separator
CFArraySetValueAtIndex(filename_arr, 1, CFSTR("_"));

// insert name
CFStringRef file_name = mKitManager.CreatePartName(part); // creates and returns a new CFStringRef
CFArraySetValueAtIndex(filename_arr, 2, file_name);
printf("file_name string length: %d\n", CFStringGetLength(file_name));

// add file type extension
CFStringRef file_ext = CFSTR(".aif");
CFArraySetValueAtIndex(filename_arr, 3, file_ext);

// create full file name
CFStringRef full_file_name = CFStringCreateByCombiningStrings(kCFAllocatorDefault, filename_arr, CFSTR(""));
printf("full_file_name string length: %d\n", CFStringGetLength(full_file_name));
```

Under some conditions the resulting combined string is shorter than it should be.  For example, when I insert the name string at index 2 I also check the string length, say that length is 10 characters.

After calling CFStringCreateByCombiningStrings the resulting string is sometimes only 3 characters long.  The first two elements have been correctly combined but only the first character of the name string has been added and the file extension completely disregarded.

I can reproduce this but have no idea why it happening.  A possible bug?

*Edit: Found a workaround for the problem.  I think the issue relates to retain counts on the CFStringRef name object but i can't get to the bottom of why it works in some circumstances and not in others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> CFMutableArrayRef filename_arr = CFArrayCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
> ```

You have created an empty array.

> ```
> CFArraySetValueAtIndex(filename_arr, 0, part_str);
> CFArraySetValueAtIndex(filename_arr, 1, CFSTR("_"));
> CFArraySetValueAtIndex(filename_arr, 2, file_name);
> CFArraySetValueAtIndex(filename_arr, 3, file_ext);
> ```

And then tried to replace the first through fourth elements of the empty array.

I'm surprised you got as far as that `CFStringCreateByCombiningStrings` call. NSMutableArray would have thrown an exception.

[The documentation for the `CFArraySetValueAtIndex` function](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableArrayRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFArraySetValueAtIndex) says that you can only use it to replace objects already in the array:

> The index … must not lie outside the index space of `theArray` (`0` to `N-1` inclusive, where `N` is the count of the array before the operation).

You want `CFArrayInsertValueAtIndex` or `CFArrayAppendValue`.

Comment: Aha, good catch. I was assuming the array would grow automatically.

Comment: @Dave DeLong: So was the questioner, I think. ☺

Comment: I am creating an empty array with an unlimited capacity.  Neither CFArrayInsertValueAtIndex nor CFArrayAppendValue are performing any better and in fact are causing crashes.  Whether this is due to an underlying memory management issue on my behalf I cannot verify.

Comment: My use of the objects prior to adding them to the array is rather complicated.  I can find no reference in the documentation that states CFArraySetValueAtIndex should only be used to replace objects.  I have been using the exact same technique of creating an empty array and setting values without problems for months now.

Comment: Stephen Blinkhorn: Capacity doesn't matter, and it isn't a *should* issue, it's a *can* issue—CFArraySetValueAtIndex doesn't append, only replace, and you cannot replace anything in an empty array. I cited in my answer the relevant part of the documentation. If the correct functions cause crashes, then that definitely does suggest a memory management problem; run your app under the Zombies instrument to find it.

Comment: Peter: Thanks, I get it. I overlooked the part of the documentation you cited. I'll take a look at the Zombies instrument.   CFStringCreateByCombiningStrings must be doing something under the hood that highlights why CFArraySetValueAtIndex cannot be used in the way I am using it. My current workaround must be causing a leak somewhere for it to work properly.

Comment: That shouldn't be possible—`CFArraySetValueAtIndex` should simply fail (or, better yet, throw an exception). The array should still be empty by the time you get to `CFStringCreateByCombiningStrings`. I think I'll copy your code to a test app and see what it does in isolation.

Comment: Well, I get the expected output. Interesting that `CFArraySetValueAtIndex` appears to work the same as `CFArrayInsertValue` when the index doesn't exist—makes me wonder which is wrong, the implementation or the documentation. No over-release/under-retain in the code you showed; please edit your question to have the code with the releases.

Answer (score 0):

Your total lack of `CFRelease()` calls leads me to believe this is a memory management problem.  Are you aware that every Core Foundation object returned by a function with "Create" in it returns an owned object?  (See: ["The Create Rule"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029))

Comment: Even if he is leaking all the objects and didn't just elide the memory management, that still wouldn't cause the objects to malfunction. That should only be a possibility if he were to release them and then try to use them afterward.

Comment: Yes, I know about the create rule and opted to not show my CFRelease() calls since, as the above commenter pointed out, it wouldn't actually have any bearing on the problem I'm experiencing and asking about.